# Uploading user files to random generated path,for each file uploaded,in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to put user files to directory which must be generating randomly for each file uploaded.How can I do this directly by editing upload_path in the config file.

Here is how my config/upload.php looks like:

```
    $config=array('upload_path' => './uploads/','allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|gif|doc|xml|zip|pdf|ppt
        docx|txt|mp4|m3u8|ts|3gp|mov|avi|wmv|mp3|aif|aifc|aiff|aac|m4a|mp1|mp2|mpeg|wav|ogg',
        'max_size' => '102400','detect_mime'=>TRUE);
?>
```

I want the output of following function to be the random directory name:

```
    public function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max)
{
     $range = $max - $min;
     if ($range < 1) return $min; // not so random...
     $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
     $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
     $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
    do 
    {
          $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
         $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    }
     while ($rnd >= $range);
    return $min + $rnd;
}

public function getRandom($length)
{
    $token = "";
     $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
     $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
     $max = strlen($codeAlphabet) - 1;
     for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) 
     {
         $token .= $codeAlphabet[$this->crypto_rand_secure(0, $max)];
    }
    return $token;
}
public $random='./uploads/'.$this->getRandom(32);
mkdir($random);
```

How to pass this random directory into upload_path in config/upload.php file?

Or how can I edit config/upload.php to

```
$config=array('upload_path' => *random_value_here*,'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|gif|doc|xml|zip|pdf|ppt
        docx|txt|mp4|m3u8|ts|3gp|mov|avi|wmv|mp3|aif|aifc|aiff|aac|m4a|mp1|mp2|mpeg|wav|ogg',
        'max_size' => '102400','detect_mime'=>TRUE);
```

so that it should take the random value from somewhere without causing duplicate object generation (ie; duplicate directory generation)

Comment: in your controller  put this code $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; before upload's actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You are so many allowed file extension. Sort out your files and random generated sub directory path.

```
if(isset($_FILES['File'])){
   $Ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['File']["name"])));
   $UploadPath = 'uploads/'.$Ext.'/'.rand(1, 1000).'/'; 

   if(!is_dir($upload_path)) {
       mkdir(FCPATH.$UploadPath, 0777, TRUE);
       chmod(FCPATH.$UploadPath, 0777);
   }
   $UploadPath = FCPATH.$UploadPath;
   // And encrypt your file name
   $config = ['upload_path'=>$UploadPath,'allowed_types'=>'jpg|png|gif|doc|xml|zip|pdf|ppt|docx|txt|mp4|m3u8|ts|3gp|mov|avi|wmv|mp3|aif|aifc|aiff|aac|m4a|mp1|mp2|mpeg|wav|ogg','encrypt_name'=>true]
}
```